# How to convert NgbDate to js Date object?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngb-datepicker

I am using an ng-bootstrap `ngbDate` object.
I would like to convert it to a standard `Date` object.
How do you do this?

Here is the relevant part of the `.ts` file:

```
import {NgbCalendar, NgbDate} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
fromDate: NgbDate;
toDate: NgbDate;
constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
    this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
    this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [ngb-date.ts](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/ngb-date.ts), NgbDate is just a container for year, month and day.

So, you could just do:

```
const jsDate = new Date(ngbDate.year, ngbDate.month - 1, ngbDate.day);
```